# script to clear folder/drive on boot

Tags: disk, drive, tmp, udisks

I want to make my own /tmp folder on one of my drives /media/Torrents
How would I go about create a script to run on startup applications? I already have this script where it mounts the drive on boot: 
    udisks --mount /dev/sdb2

The folder I want to get wiped every boot will be called .tmp

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get the question right, you want a folder's content to be deleted on boot.
The script could look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
folder=/your/folder/here
rm -r "$folder"/*
```

To use it you only change the second line: replace /your/folder/here with the folder you want wiped. Then copy/paste it into an empty text file (not using something like libreoffice or Open Office, but with something like gedit). Save it as whateveryouwant.sh. Right click on it, go to "Properties"->"Permissions" and check the box to make it executable.

There are lots of options to run it at system start up. There should even be a graphical tool in Ubuntu to let stuff run at log in, that might be easiest if you don't need it earlier.

Comment: So if I'm correct for me it'll be: #!/bin/bash
folder=/media/Torrents/.tmp
rm -r "$.tmp"/*

Comment: I wrote a general script on purpose because I don't understand your question completely. If the folder you want wiped is /media/Torrents/.tmp then you change the second line to
folder=/media/Torrents/.tmp
and leave everything else. You weren't supposed to edit the third line, the third line like I wrote it does the following: Remove everything inside the folder which you specified in the second line.
You also can't remove the newlines I put in. You need to paste it into a file exactly like I wrote it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now, yes I want to remove /media/Torrents/.tmp. Thank you very much!